# Table header values within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I want to display a table with header values inside ng-repeat. The code I have at present is as follows

```
<table>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                              <table class="table">

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Leave Application Date</td>
                                    <td>Date from:</td>
                                    <td>Date To:</td>
                                    <td>Status</td>
                                    <td>Employee Name</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr ng-repeat="leaveApp in leaveApplicationCollection" class="row">


                                    <td>
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td >{{leaveApp.leaveApplicationDate}}</td>
                                                <td >{{leaveApp.dateFrom}}</td>
                                                <td >{{leaveApp.dateTo}}</td>
                                                <td >{{leaveApp.status}}</td>
                                                <td >{{leaveApp.employee.fullName}}</td>
                                                <td><a ng-click="showLeaveDetails(leaveApp.id)"><span><i class='icon-search3 pull-left'></i></span></a>
                                                <a ng-click="showLeaveCancelModal(leaveApp.id)"><i class='icon-cancel-circle'></i></a>
                                                </td>

                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td ng-show=isIdActive(leaveApp.id)>Leave App details</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    </div>



        </tr>

    </table>
```

The problem is that it shows the entire second table under the first heading and the other headings contain no data.

I was wondering if it would be possible to use $first to set the headings.

Please suggest a solution.

PS:I have a constraint.

I have to have the second table inside a td. This is because I need to show an element let's say 'Leave Application Details' appear right below the row when the leave application row is clicked. This is my constraint.

Comment: Because you have only one `td` and inside that you have entire `table`!

Comment: remove the  <td>
                                        <table> tags

Comment: sorry i wanted to edit the equestion. I have to have the table inside a td. This is because I need to show an element let's say 'Leave Application Details' appear right below the row when the leave application row is clicked. This is my constraint.

Comment: In your first table row (tr) you have 5 table data tags (td's) and in your second tr you have only one td. Either you collumn span that one td over 5 columns or you create 5 td's

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**`<thead>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead) and [**`<tbody>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) tags as follows:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr class=row>
      <td>Leave Application Date</td>
      <td>Date from:</td>
      <td>Date To:</td>
      <td>Status</td>
      <td>Employee Name</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="leaveApp in leaveApplicationCollection">
    <tr class="row">
      <td>{{leaveApp.leaveApplicationDate}}</td>
      <td>{{leaveApp.dateFrom}}</td>
      <td>{{leaveApp.dateTo}}</td>
      <td>{{leaveApp.status}}</td>
      <td>{{leaveApp.employee.fullName}}</td>
      <td>
        <a ng-click="showLeaveDetails(leaveApp.id)">
          <i class="icon-search3 pull-left"></i>
        </a>
        <a ng-click="showLeaveCancelModal(leaveApp.id)">
          <i class="icon-cancel-circle"></i>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row" ng-show="isIdActive(leaveApp.id)">
      <td colspan="6">
         Leave App details
         XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also note the addition of the `colspan="6"` attribute on the single `<td>` within the second `<tr>` to ensure that spans all columns.

[**Example Plunk**](https://plnkr.co/edit/9HVIUa6HrkT5TwvE5zfu?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                              <table class="table">    
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Leave Application Date</th>
                                    <th>Date from:</th>
                                    <th>Date To:</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr ng-repeat="leaveApp in leaveApplicationCollection" class="row">

                                                <td >{{leaveApp.leaveApplicationDate}}</td>
                                                <td >{{leaveApp.dateFrom}}</td>
                                                <td >{{leaveApp.dateTo}}</td>
                                                <td >{{leaveApp.status}}</td>
                                                <td >{{leaveApp.employee.fullName}}</td>
                                                <td><a ng-click="showLeaveDetails(leaveApp.id)"><span><i class='icon-search3 pull-left'></i></span></a>
                                                <a ng-click="showLeaveCancelModal(leaveApp.id)"><i class='icon-cancel-circle'></i></a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td ng-show=isIdActive(leaveApp.id)>Leave App details</td>
                                            </tr>

                                        </table>

                                    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work now as expected.

```
<table><tr><td>
<div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                              <table class="table">

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Leave Application Date</td>
                                    <td>Date from:</td>
                                    <td>Date To:</td>
                                    <td>Status</td>
                                    <td>Employee Name</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr ng-repeat="leaveApp in leaveApplicationCollection" class="row">
                                                <td >{{leaveApp.leaveApplicationDate}}</td>
                                                <td >{{leaveApp.dateFrom}}</td>
                                                <td >{{leaveApp.dateTo}}</td>
                                                <td >{{leaveApp.status}}</td>
                                                <td >{{leaveApp.employee.fullName}}</td>
                                                <td><a ng-click="showLeaveDetails(leaveApp.id)"><span><i class='icon-search3 pull-left'></i></span></a>
                                                <a ng-click="showLeaveCancelModal(leaveApp.id)"><i class='icon-cancel-circle'></i></a>
                                                </td>

                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td ng-show=isIdActive(leaveApp.id)>Leave App details</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div></div>
    </td></tr></table>
```